# OpenCV running slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have got OpenCV installed on vs2010/win7 however I'm seeing some behaviour that I can't figure out.

I am new to OpenCV so just have a basic program to pull frames from an avi file - it then splits that frame into single channel images and generates histograms for each of those (taken from an internet example). It actually all works fine, it's just *extremely* slow. It turns out that cvFillConvexPoly is actually taking 10-15 seconds (sometimes longer) to complete - but when it eventually returns it is correct.

This is the code snippet where I call the culprit function and as you can see I also tried cvFillPoly which took the same amount of time to complete.

```
IplImage* DrawHistogram(CvHistogram *hist, float sX)
{
    float histMax = 0;
    cvGetMinMaxHistValue(hist, 0, &histMax, 0, 0);

    IplImage *imgHist = cvCreateImage(cvSize(256, 64), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvZero(imgHist);

    float histValue = 0;
    float nextValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ((BINS - 1)*sX); i++)
    {
        histValue = cvQueryHistValue_1D(hist, i);
        nextValue = cvQueryHistValue_1D(hist, i + 1);

        CvPoint p1 = cvPoint(i * sX, 64);
        CvPoint p2 = cvPoint((i + 1) * sX, 64);
        CvPoint p3 = cvPoint((i + 1) * sX, 64 - histValue*(64/histMax));
        CvPoint p4 = cvPoint(i * sX, 64 - histValue*(64/histMax));

        int n = 5;
        CvPoint pts[] = {p1, p2, p3, p4};

        cvFillConvexPoly(imgHist, pts, n, cvScalar(255));
        //cvFillPoly(imgHist, pts, &n, 1,cvScalar(255));
    }

    return imgHist;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Compiled on Win7 x64 with CMake 2.8.2/VS2010 as 32 bit. Same behaviour when debugging and when running as a standalone.

Also have it running on Ubuntu 10.10 32 bit, compiled with gcc 4.4.5 where there **isn't** a problem.

---

Edit

I've tried recompiling with VS2008 and it still does the same thing. I don't understand what would cause it to run so slowly - unless it's the way 64bit windows "emulates" 32 bit which is causing the problem.

Comment: To be sure: timings are all on the same machine? And how slow is slow compared to the other results?

Comment: Ubuntu is installed on a slower machine, when I run it on there that above function (DrawHistogram) runs in less than a second. On my windows machine it takes over half an hour (I stopped watching the clock and just let it finish)

Comment: @tom502 maybe your windows machine has a smaller cache so you get much more cache misses

Comment: @tom502 in short: when you're lucky the core of your program fits into the CPU cache, if not the CPU must wait for RAM. see [CPU Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_misses)

Comment: Ahh right ok... Well it's not that - 6M cache on win7 pc and 2M on the other

Comment: did you build using TBB?

Comment: It looks like you are filling in a rectangle whose dimensions depend on the histogram values? Can you give the values of the corners? I would typically put some type of boundary check on those. Also, what if you made the call fill in only a small patch like 10x10. How long does that take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can spot 2 possible bugs in your code, both of which have to do with bounds. Reading/writing outside array boundaries may result in all kinds of unexpected behavior, so it's a wonder your programs don't crash. Maybe GCC and/or the OpenCV library behaves differently on Ubuntu and Windows causing it not to crash on Ubuntu, but you should definitely take a look at the following 2 points.

1. I assume `sX` is a scaling factor? Your `for` loop should run from `0` to `(BINS-1)` no matter this scaling, since you're using `i` to index your histogram and there are `BINS` bins, not `BINS*sX`. As long as `sX == 1` you won't run into trouble but any other value will invalidate your histogram drawing code. You are already using `sX` in its correct way too in the `cvPoint` declarations.
2. According to the docs of the [`cvFillConvexPoly`](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_ImageProcessing.htm#decl_cvFillConvexPoly) function, `n` should be the number of points, which is 4 in your case, not 5.

Comment: OH MY........ I didn't notice the 4 as a 5. Thanks, you've just saved me pulling my hair out. Now to investigate why that doesn't cause problems on Linux!